# How to find children of children's context in ANTLR?

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

As the title say, is there a way to find the children of children node when listen or visit a node in ANTLR.

For example: (use grammars-v4-java lexer and parse rule)

First, I take a java file to grammar tree.

```sh
grun Java compilationUnit  -gui Example.java
```

```java
// Example.java
public class Example {
    String name = "test";
    void call(){
        String name1 = "test";
    }
}
```

and the grammar tree is

[image: Example.java grammar tree.png(picture)]

Then I try to use java to extends the baseListerner to listen `enterClassDeclaration` node. So I can get the `ClassDeclarationContext` node. I want to find the `ClassDeclarationContext` node's children of children that the child type is `LocalDeclarationContext`.

In this example:

```
public class MyListener extends JavaParserBaseListener {
    @Override
    public void enterClassDeclaration(JavaParser.ClassDeclarationContext ctx) {
        // find the children of children by ctx
        List<ParserRuleContext> contexts = findChildContextBy(ctx, LocalVariableDeclarationContext.class);
        super.enterClassDeclaration(ctx);
    }
}
```

The variable `contexts` should has two elements. `name` and `name1`

I do not want to find the children one layer by one layer. emmm, Is there have a convenient way?

Comment: Why not listen to `enterLocalDeclaration` instead?

Comment: yeah, this is a good way to listen a specified node context.  That mean I need to override the specify event method. But I want to know is there has a way or a API can find the children of children. like the description of question. `findChildContextBy(ctx, LocalVariableDeclarationContext.class);`. I just need to pass a context class param instead of override different event method. Or  this way is not good ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a given parse tree it's easy to look up specific child nodes (at any nesting level) using [ANTLR4's XPath implementation](https://github.com/mike-lischke/antlr4/blob/master/doc/tree-matching.md).

You can trigger that search from either the full parse tree return by the called parser rule or within a listener/visitor method for the particular subtree, for example:

```
List<ParseTreeMatch> matches = XPath.findAll(ctx, "//localVariableDeclaration", parser);
```

The return matches are instances of `LocalVariableDeclarationContext` (if any matched).

Note: the linked page describe two search utilities, parse tree matching and XPath, which can be used individually or together.

Comment: I think use parse tree matching and XPath together is a good choice. Thanks, Mike.